# MobileWiFi framework callback in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

For a private project I'm trying to use the private MobileWiFi framework in Swift.

I found this website:
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework
In Objective-C it's working like a charm, but I want to convert the code to Swift.

I have converted the function "Retrieving a list of known networks" into Swift already and that function is working.

Now I'm trying to convert the "Getting the WiFi signal strength" function but the uses a callback function and I have tried so hard, but can't get it to work.

```
   #include <MobileWiFi.h>

static WiFiManagerRef _manager;
static void scan_callback(WiFiDeviceClientRef device, CFArrayRef results, CFErrorRef error, void *token);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    _manager = WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);

    CFArrayRef devices = WiFiManagerClientCopyDevices(_manager);
    if (!devices) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get WiFi devices. Bailing.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    WiFiDeviceClientRef client = (WiFiDeviceClientRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(devices, 0);

    WiFiManagerClientScheduleWithRunLoop(_manager, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    WiFiDeviceClientScanAsync(client, (CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary dictionary], scan_callback, 0);

    CFRelease(devices);

    CFRunLoopRun();

        return 0;
}

static void scan_callback(WiFiDeviceClientRef device, CFArrayRef results, CFErrorRef error, void *token)
{
    NSLog(@"Finished scanning! networks: %@", results);

    WiFiManagerClientUnscheduleFromRunLoop(_manager);
    CFRelease(_manager);

    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
```

Can someone explain to me how to use such a callback function in the swift language?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found this function:

```
pcap_loop(pcapSession, numberOfPackets,
{
    (args: UnsafeMutablePointer<u_char>,
     pkthdr:UnsafePointer<pcap_pkthdr>,
     packet: UnsafePointer<u_char>) ->Void in

            // singleton call
            let pa = PacketAnalyser.sharedInstance
            pa.Process()
},
nil)
```

On this website: http://diydeveloper.io/tech/2015/11/27/swift-pcap

I think this is a posible solution for my problem. Can somebody explain to me if I can use this example?

Comment: I believe this is only a solution for OSX as pcap sniffing on iOS does not yield WiFi network names